# Transfer NuGet Package from one computer to another

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, file-transfer

I am building a WPF application now but I am completely new to VS 2013.

One of my friend wants to work on this project with me so I copied my project directory to his computer.

The project doesn't work on his computer because there is a package missing. I redownloaded that package but it turns out that something I referenced in my project were deleted in the newer version of the package.

Is there a way that I can copy the existing NuGet Package on my computer to his computer?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can install a specific version of a package using the following command in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio:

   ```
   Install-Package YourPackageId -Version 1.2.3
   ```
2. You find the installed packages...

   a) in the `packages` folder under your the solution folder.

   b) in the package cache: `%LocalAppData%\Nuget\Cache`.
3. Copy the package over to your friend's computer and put it in `c:\LocalPackages\` for example. Then, add this path as local package source: [Managing NuGet Packages Using the Dialog / Package Sources](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog#Package_Sources)